# How to move bubble with value of input type range

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Currently I'm trying to figure out how to move bubble which contains current value of input type="range" element. I mean my goal is when I move slider-thumb , the bubble will move with it too ,so the bubble will be always above the slider-thumb.

I've tried to google it,but all I can find was how to style that div to look like bubble and some small code to display that exactly above slider thumb ,but It does not work for me and I can't really figure it out how to make it work or how to calculate the position where to display it.

**Code that i've found**

```
const
    range = document.getElementById('range'),
    rangeV = document.getElementById('rangeV'),
    setValue = ()=>{
        const
            newValue = Number( (range.value - range.min) * 100 / (range.max - range.min) ),
            newPosition = 10 - (newValue * 0.2);
        rangeV.innerHTML = `<span>${range.value}</span>`;
        rangeV.style.left = `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))`;
    };
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setValue);
range.addEventListener('input', setValue);
```

I'm working in React ,and the result of this will be BMI calculator app.

Has anybody encountered this type of problem? I'll be glad for every advice or explanation . Thank you.

codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-tereshkova-ujk45?file=/src/Components/Button.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not advisable to use vanilla javascript for uncontrolled components in react. See [React useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). But you already have the solution. All you need do is put that snippet in a useEffect() hook in Range.js.

In `Range.js`

```
function Range(props) {

  useEffect(() => {
    const
    range = document.getElementById('range'),
    rangeV = document.getElementById('rangeV'),
    setValue = ()=>{
        const
            newValue = Number( (range.value - range.min) * 100 / (range.max - range.min) ),
            newPosition = 10 - (newValue * 0.2);
        rangeV.innerHTML = `<span>${range.value}</span>`;
        rangeV.style.left = `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))`;
    };
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setValue);
range.addEventListener('input', setValue);
  }, [])

...//rest of Range.js
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/7wmgspvq/3/

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've encountered small problem.When page loads ,the bubble is on the left side of the input type range. If i remove that span on the beginning ,there is no bubble at the start,but when I click a try to drag slider, then it appears. Is there any ways to make the bubble above the slider when the page loads?